# AES DEcryption in CTR mode (Java)

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, encryption

I have these information:

CTR key: 36f18357be4dbd77f050515c73fcf9f2

CTR Ciphertext 1:69dda8455c7dd4254bf353b773304eec0ec7702330098ce7f7520d1cbbb20fc3
88d1b0adb5054dbd7370849dbf0b88d393f252e764f1f5f7ad97ef79d59ce29f5f51eeca32eabedd9afa9329

Note that  the 16-byte encryption IV is chosen at random and is prepended to the ciphertext. And the text is encrypted with AES in CTR mode.

I have to discover the plaintext
To do this I have written a short Java program but it doesn't work and I don't find why :/

This is the Java program

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AES {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    //Dernier exemple CTR mode
    //Clé 16 bits 
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[] { (byte)0x36,(byte)0xf1,(byte)0x83,(byte)0x57,(byte)0xbe,(byte)0x4d,(byte)0xbd,(byte)0x77,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x50,(byte)0x51,(byte)0x5c,0x73,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0xf9,(byte)0xf2};
    //IV 16 bits (préfixe du cipherText)
    byte[] ivBytes = new byte[] {(byte)0x69,(byte)0xdd,(byte)0xa8,(byte)0x45,(byte)0x5c,(byte)0x7d,(byte)0xd4,(byte)0x25,(byte)0x4b,(byte)0xf3,(byte)0x53,(byte)0xb7,(byte)0x73,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x4e,(byte)0xec};
    
    //Initialisation
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
    
    //Mode
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
    
    byte[]  cipherText = new byte[] {(byte)0x0e,(byte)0xc,(byte)0x77,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x33,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x98,(byte)0xce,(byte)0x7f,(byte)0x75,(byte)0x20,(byte)0xd1,(byte)0xcb,(byte)0xbb,(byte)0x20,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x38,(byte)0x8d,(byte)0x1b,(byte)0x0a,(byte)0xdb,(byte)0x50,(byte)0x54,(byte)0xdb,(byte)0xd7,(byte)0x37,(byte)0x08,(byte)0x49,(byte)0xdb,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0xb8,(byte)0x8d,(byte)0x39,(byte)0x3f,(byte)0x25,(byte)0x2e,(byte)0x76,(byte)0x4f,(byte)0x1f,(byte)0x5f,(byte)0x7a,(byte)0xd9,(byte)0x7e,(byte)0xf7,(byte)0x9d,(byte)0x59,(byte)0xce,(byte)0x29,(byte)0xf5,(byte)0xf5,(byte)0x1e,(byte)0xec,(byte)0xa3,(byte)0x2e,(byte)0xab,(byte)0xed,(byte)0xd9,(byte)0xaf,(byte)0xa9,(byte)0x32,(byte)0x29}; 
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);  
    byte [] original = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
    String plaintext = new String(original);
    System.out.println("plaintext: " + plaintext );
}
```

}

The result is

```
=> plaintext: CŸUnfpL¨KH¹)VPÅ|ÉÒ9}FÅgÿ žQ3Š®¹zÛ˜ˆ±<þãh¤ÔÆË“M±§|@+0H5§
```

So it seems to be wrong

Comment: Ciphertext and plain text consists of bytes, not characters. So after a direct translation to the *system character set* you may not get something that is printable. Make sure that you use the correct character set for the `String` constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There could be other problems, but the cipher text in your question, after the 16 first bytes, starts with `0ec770`, whereas the cipher text in the Java code starts with

```
0x0e, 0xc, 0x77
```

They don't match.