# AES 128 CTR Mode in Ruby

Tags: ruby, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm trying to decrypt some cipher text in CBC and CTR mode. The IV is said to be the first 16 bytes of the cipher text. I wrote this function in Ruby to solve it and with `CBC`, I got the correct results but as soon as I changed the mode to `CTR`, I get a random string of bytes.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29988869/ruby-openssl-aes-128-ctr) [and this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659795/aes-decryption-in-ctr-mode-java) ask similar questions, but neither were using the correct IV text and I've check mine multiple times.

```
def decrypt(key, cipher, mode=:CBC)
  k = [key].pack('H*')
  iv = [cipher.scan(/../).first(16).join].pack('H*')
  c = [cipher].pack('H*')

  aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(128, mode)
  aes.decrypt
  aes.iv = iv
  aes.key = k
  aes.update(c) + aes.final
end
```

With mode=CBC (Correct with disregared first few bytes):

```
decrypt('140b41b22a29beb4061bda66b6747e14', '4ca00ff4c898d61e1edbf1800618fb2828a226d160dad07883d04e008a7897ee2e4b7465d5290d0c0e6c6822236e1daafb94ffe0c5da05d9476be028ad7c1d81')
=> "LQ\xFCXTr@\t\xC7\eb\x0Ex\xB3\nQBasic CBC mode encryption needs padding."
```

With mode=CTR:

```
decrypt('36f18357be4dbd77f050515c73fcf9f2', '69dda8455c7dd4254bf353b773304eec0ec7702330098ce7f7520d1cbbb20fc388d1b0adb5054dbd7370849dbf0b88d393f252e764f1f5f7ad97ef79d59ce29f5f51eeca32eabedd9afa9329', :CTR)
=> "$N\x8AF\x01\e<\xA7\x9C\xCD;\xDF\xBB\xA28@\xF36\xA2\xFB\xEC`\xA5z\xE5\x02\xFA\xF5v\xDC\xE6};@\x8B:\xB9\x91\xCAj\xB8\x95\x04\x89J\xF6J.\xA0\xCC\xDFFvx\"Z_\b\x0E~[\x1F\x92+&U\xEB\x9E\xE0\xA7}\r\xC9Y?\xB2"
```

Comment: First of all, you're forgetting to strip off the IV before decryption. Second, are you sure you need the same key? And that the IV is not an 8 byte nonce for CTR?

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much. Just stripping the IV out of the cipher text worked

Comment: You're welcome... if you don't mind I'll keep from answering though (so you can wait for somebody else, write an answer yourself or delete, whichever your fancy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Maarten's help in the comments above, I was able to refine my method to not include the IV in the cipher text when decrypting.

```
def decrypt(key, cipher, mode=:CBC)
  k = [key].pack('H*')
  bytes = cipher.scan(/../)
  iv = [bytes[0..15].join].pack('H*')
  c = [bytes[16..-1].join].pack('H*')

  aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES128.new(mode)
  aes.decrypt
  aes.iv = iv
  aes.key = k
  aes.update(c) + aes.final
end
```